# Не работает AccessControl. Не запускается AccessRule, даже если он переопределен

Tags: php, yii2, access-control, behaviors

Пытаюсь понять почему не отрабатывают ни стандартные, ни кастомные AccessRule. Реализован RBAC через DbManager, модуль качал отсюда https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin. И так что мы имеем:

**3 контроллера:**

- `class AdminController extends BehaviorsController` - Админка
- `class SiteController extends BehaviorsController` - Сайт
- `class BehaviorsController extends Controller` - Общий контроллер с поведениями (behaviors)

**В методе `behaviors()` контроллера `BehaviorsController` описано следующее:**

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['login'],
                    'controllers' => ['admin'],
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['index', 'article', 'logout'],
                    'controllers' => ['admin'],
                    'roles' => ['admin'],
                ]
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post']
            ]
        ],
    ];
}
```

**Содержимое таблиц в БД:**

- auth_item:

  - admin | 2
  - owner | 2
- auth_item_child:

  - owner | admin
- auth_assignment:

  - owner | 1

При всем этом зайти на `/web/index.php?r=admin/index` (не обязательно на index, заходит на все указанные методы) можно даже под не авторизованным пользователем.

Пробовал проводить проверки типа `Yii::$app->user->can('owner')` в контроллерах, все проверяется правильно. Даже если объявить в общем контроллере `(BehaviorsController) beforeAction` и реализовать там проверку прав через `Yii::$app->user->can` все будет работать.

Пробовал дебажить. В классе `yii\filters\AccessRule` проставлял `die()` в начале каждого метода - ни один не отрабатывает. При этом в `yii\filters\AccessControl::init()` вроде бы попадаю и настройки из `behaviors` туда все передаются.

Пробовал определять свой `AccessRule` унаследованный от `yii\filters\AccessRule`, естественно в `behaviors()` тоже указывал его, в `ruleConfig`, результат тот же - даже не запускается.

Вопрос в том, почему не работают проверки через `behaviors`, если сам rbac работает замечательно? Почему не запускаются `AccessRule`? Возможно они и не должны запускаться - не знаю, пока только разбираюсь во всем этом.

На всех форумах написано одно и тоже: пишите behaviors и будет вам счастье. Все видюхи тоже говорят об одном и том же. Ну не знаю... может кто сталкивался с таким? Если нужны еще какие нибудь данные для ответа - спрашивайте, предоставлю.

Вообще, в идеале мне нужно прокидывать 403 для всех у кого роль ниже admin и потом на страницу авторизации, если не авторизован.

Comment: покажите код SiteController, может быть Вы там переопределили public function behaviors